What can you do at the Thomson station on the Walhalla goldfields railway?
I was looking at the time table for the Walhalla Gold fields railway (www.walhallarail.com.au) and noticed it had a stop called "Thomson". Going by the timetable I should be able to take the 11:00 am, get off at Thomson at 11:40 then get back on at 1:40 to return to Walhalla at 2pm.

What is at Thomson station, is it worth a look? Map of area

You would actually get to Thomson at 11:20, not 11:40,  it’s 20 minutes each way.

If you dig into the immediate area on Google Maps it looks as if the Walhalla Railways runs from Walhalla Station to Thomson Station. It's a distance of about 3km, which sounds about right for a narrow gauge tourist train in 20 minutes. Both are on the C461 road, and you could drive between them in 5 minutes. There is a hiking trail right a long the road and you could walk there in an hour. Road, rail and hike follow about the same path, so it's not like you are going to get much better views from the train.
There appear to be lots of hiking trails by Thomson Station, and the Walhalla Railway reserve, and a couple of campgrounds. The nearest town is Rawson about a 2km hike away.
If you don't have transport then it might be nice to stay at one of the campgrounds, but if you have a car then I would just treat the railway as a nice 2 way ride for an hour and drive to wherever you want to hike.
